# Programmatically Enable/Disable camera in iOS for all applications (globally)

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to **programmatically enable or disable camera globally** (i.e. restrict for all the application)

I have seen in **Settings -> General -> Restrictions** we can actually enable or disable camera, but is it possible programmatically?

In android we can use **MDM (Mobile Device Management)** to control this feature, is it possible in iOS also using swift code?

Comment: No, of course not, luckily. At least not via any public API.

Comment: As with your Android comment, you can do this via MDM with iOS devices.

Comment: Tks for your comments, I have to create some security related project, where when employees come to the office, there mobile camera should automatically disable after scanning QR code, i have already achieved this in android, and its working fine, is there any other alternative to achieve this use case in ios?

Comment: @DonMag can you give more detail about, how can I do this via MDM in iOS devices?

Comment: @AmitChauhan : Did you find solution to disable Camera in iOS devices?

Comment: @Jatin noop, this is not possible in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to disable camera programmetically in iOS. 
You have to enforce disable camera payload on iOS devices through MDM.